# java - how to kill a Process if it exceeds an alloted time

Tags: java, multithreading, timeout, runnable

I am wondering what the best way is to detect/kill a process if it exceeds a predefined time. I know an old way was to use the watchdog/timeoutobserver class from the ant package. But this is deprecated now, so I am wondering how it should be done now?

Here is the code I have which uses watchdog:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.util.Watchdog;
import org.apache.tools.ant.util.TimeoutObserver;


public class executer implements TimeoutObserver {

    private int timeOut = 0;
    Process process = null;
    private boolean killedByTimeout =false;


    public executer(int to) {
        timeOut = t;
    }

    public String executeCommand() throws Exception {
        Watchdog watchDog = null;
        String templine = null;
        StringBuffer outputTrace = new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer errorTrace = new StringBuffer();



        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();



        try {
            //instantiate a new watch dog to kill the process
            //if exceeds beyond the time
            watchDog = new Watchdog(getTimeout());
            watchDog.addTimeoutObserver(this);
            watchDog.start();

            process = runtime.exec(command);

            //... Code to do the execution .....

            InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            while (((templine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) && (!processWasKilledByTimeout)) {
                outputTrace.append(templine);
                outputTrace.append("\n");
            }


            this.setStandardOut(outputTrace);


            int returnCode = process.waitFor();
            //Set the return code
            this.setReturnCode(returnCode);

            if (processWasKilledByTimeout) {
                //As process was killed by timeout just throw an exception
                throw new InterruptedException("Process was killed before the waitFor was reached.");
            }


        } finally {
            // stop the watchdog as no longer needed.
            if (aWatchDog != null) {
                aWatchDog.stop();
            }
            try {
                // close buffered readers etc
            } catch Exception() {
            }
            //Destroy process
            //    Process.destroy() sends a SIGTERM to the process. The default action
            //    when SIGTERM is received is to terminate, but any process is free to
            //    ignore the signal or catch it and respond differently.
            //
            //    Also, the process started by Java might have created additional
            //    processes that don't receive the signal at all.
            if(process != null) {

                process.destroy();
            }
        }



        public void timeoutOccured(Watchdog arg0) {
            killedByTimeout = true;

            if (process != null){
                process.destroy();
            }
            arg0.stop();
        }

    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am a bit lost. I am trying to take this up to Java 7, but I am not uptodate with the best way to kill it if it hangs beyond the alloted time.

Thanks,

Comment: send an interrupt to the thread.

Comment: get system time in miliseconds, after passed time you want, call finalize();

Comment: Please make your question clear: are you killing a "Thread" or a "Process"? (from your code it seems to be latter one, but what you were asking is misleading)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
    final Process p = ... 
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                p.destroy();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        };
    };
    p.waitFor();
    t.interrupt();
```

Comment: That's what I looked for! But `t.start();` forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically Thread has method `stop()` that totally kills the thread. This method is deprecated since java 1.1 because it may cause resources leak. So, you are really not recommended to use it.

The "right" solution is to implement your thread so that they can gracefully exit when receiving a special "signal". You can use "interruption" mechanism: your watchdog should call "interrupt()" of thread that exceeds the time limit. But thread should call `isInterrupted()` itself and exit if it is interrupted. The good news is that method like `sleep()` and `wait()` already support this, so if your thread is waiting and you interrupt it from outside it `InterruptedException` will be thrown.

Comment: From the example code, I believe OP is actually asking for killing process but not thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you just concern about `WatchDog` itself is deprecated, it is nothing more difficult for you to make use of `TimerTask`, and do the `process.destroy()` after a period of time.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a set of `ExecutorServices` that will cancel processes after they have been given a certain period of time to execute. This code has been checked into GitHub.

The class to use to create the `ExecutorService` is [CancelingExecutors](https://github.com/dancerjohn/LibEx/blob/master/libex/src/main/java/org/libex/concurrent/cancelling/CancelingExecutors.java). There are two main classes:

- [CancelingListeningExecutorService](https://github.com/dancerjohn/LibEx/blob/master/libex/src/main/java/org/libex/concurrent/cancelling/CancelingListeningExecutorService.java) allows you to specify the timeout for each passed `Callable`
- [FixedTimeoutCancelingListeningExecutorService](https://github.com/dancerjohn/LibEx/blob/master/libex/src/main/java/org/libex/concurrent/cancelling/FixedTimeoutCancelingListeningExecutorService.java) is configured to use a single timeout for all `Callables`